# Unable to update State in a component through a function call ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

I am new to react native and I have been trying to solve this problem for the past few hours.
I am making a simple expenses tracker app and I have 3 components for now, homescreen, addexpensescreen and trackbudget.

I am experiencing issues in updating the total expenses on the homescreen after adding a new expense from the addexpensescreen. I used a function from trackbudget in addexpensescreen to call for an update of its state. It works when I directly assign the state to its new expense but I have to manually refresh the code on visual studio before having the change reflected on the app. So I then tried using this.setState() but a warning came out and told me that the component is unmounted.

This is my code so far.. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Trackbudget Screen:

***code***

```
class TrackBudget extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      budget: 1000,
      expenses: 500,
      cat: []
    };
  }

  updateExpenses(c) {
    //works only when i refresh the app on the homescreen page
    this.state.expenses += Number(c)

    //does not work but I think this is the proper implementation
    this.setState({ expenses: c + this.state.expenses})
  }

  budget() {
      return this.state.budget
  }

  expenses() {
      return this.state.expenses
  }}

  const budget = new TrackBudget()

  export default budget
```

HomeScreen:

***code***

```
export default function HomeScreen(props) {
    return {
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>   
            {/* Add current expenses from trackbudget*/}
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Current Expenses for the Month: </Text>
          <View>
              //This is the place where I need the expense figure to be updated but it is not updating by itself
           <Text style = {styles.expenseText}>${budget.expenses()}</Text>
         </View>
```

addExpenseScreen:

***code***

```
<BackBtn 
    onPress = { () =>  {this.reset(); alert("Submitted");
    //updating the expenses with 50bucks
    budget.updateExpenses(50)
      }}></BackBtn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions to properly bind functions to the current context -

```
  updateExpenses = (c) => { // arrow function syntax
    const expenses =  this.state.expenses + Number(c)

    this.setState({ expenses })
  }
```

And reference state values directly -

```
<Text style={styles.expenseText}>
  {this.state.expenses} // no need to call a function
</Text>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. However, im still facing the issue of this.setState({expenses}) is not able to change a state with a component that is unmounted. I am not really sure how to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your TrackBudget component being rendered? You can't update the state of an instance of the component without mounting it. If you want to set the state of TrackBudget, then it needs to be rendered.

It's not clear how these components are connected from your code. From a first pass, it seems like all of this logic should just be on your HomeScreen, and you can store the budget in the state of the Homescreen. Then on your button click, you could update the state to reflect your updated expenses. If you need the button to be on a separate screen, then you could make the addExpenseScreen a child of the HomeScreen and pass a callback to set the state of the HomeScreen.